# Is there any way to find special symbols like '?','*','NA' in a data frame containing ten thousand instances using python coding?

Tags: python, dataframe

how do i find Special characters in a data frame using python code ..and also find locations of them. for this am using regular expressions in python but i didn't get anything..

Want to display text for each columns if it contains special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering the below as the input dataframe, I have performed the operations.

```
    name    val
0   a   1
1   *   2
2   b   NaN
3   d   1
4   g   ?
5   t   3
6   h   4
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

f=pd.read_csv('data_file.csv')
f=pd.DataFrame(f)

#the below loop will provide you with the location of null values. i.e. "NaN"
for i,j in zip(*np.where(pd.isnull(f))):
    print("{},{}".format(i,j))

o/p: 2,1

#similarly finding location of '*' and '?'
special=['*','?']
for k in special:
    print(np.where(f.applymap(lambda x: x == k)),'location for ',k)

o/p: 
(array([1], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64)) location for  *
(array([4], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64)) location for  ?


eg:
i/n: f.iloc[1,0]
o/p: '*'
```